# how to use mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource and maxConnectionAge

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use the maxConnectionAge property inside my bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
   destroy-method="close">
   <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="7200" />
```

my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

the problem is that the setters and getters are not available for the property of maxConnectionAge, even when i try to create:

```
  ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
  cpds.setMaxConnectionAge() <- its not recognized by the intellisense
```

How can i use maxConnectionAge ?

the error:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps `cpds.setMaxConnectionAge(7200);`?

Comment: I've tried, not working

Comment: I'm not sure but i have used [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.2) dependency.Thats working for me

Comment: Same code working for me . Please add error if you have problem